# C++ can I make a pointer to an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Silly question but how do I make a pointer to an array in C++? My understanding is we have a pointer to the first element of an array, but what if we wanted a pointer to that pointer.

```
int arr[3] = { 1, 2, 3 };
auto arrp = &arr;

cout << arr << " " << arrp << endl;
cout << typeid(arr).name() << " " << typeid(arrp).name() << endl;

// 0115FC24 0115FC24
// int [3] int (*)[3]
```

Using the auto keyword/experimenting it seems like it can be done, but I can't type out int (*)[3] arrp = &arr;

Is there a way to type it out?

Comment: I recommend you look up "The right-left rule".

Comment: You may not actually want to do this. In C and C++, arrays decay on use to pointers to their first element. And if you want to have multiple "arrays" of length 3, just allocate a buffer (not on the stack!) of 3*n elements, and point into that. I also suggest reading the [C FAQ section about arrays and pointers](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pointers to arrays and function pointers have weird syntax.

```
int (* arrp2)[3] = &arr;
```

Comment: Thank you to everyone, this article explained right-left rule when it comes to function pointers and weird C++ syntax: [link](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/7042/how-to-interpret-complex-c-c-declarations#:~:text=The%20right-left%20rule%20%5BImportant%5D%20This%20is%20a%20simple,parentheses%2C%20go%20right%2C%20and%20then%20go%20left.%20)